# Alternative proof about divergence of of {n!/(a^n)}

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, alternative-proof

Can we find a more *elegant* or *special* proof of $\frac {n!}{a^n}\to \infty, a>0$?

For example I suggest this:

$\forall a>0\forall n\in \Bbb N:\frac {n!}{a^n}=\int _{0}^{\infty}(\frac xa)^n e^{-x}dx=\int _0^a (\frac xa)^n e^{-x}dx +\int_a^\infty (\frac xa)^n e^{-x}dx\geq \int_a^\infty (\frac xa)^n e^{-x}dx=-(\frac xa)^n e^{-x}|_a^\infty +\frac na\int_a^\infty (\frac xa)^{n-1} e^{-x}dx=...=e^{-a}(1+\frac {n}{a}+\frac {n(n-1)}{a^2}+...+\frac {n!}{a^n})\geq \frac {e^{-a}}{a}n\to \infty.$

P.S. I am asking about a *non trivial* answer.

Comment: Hi. Please use more descriptive titles

Comment: Convergence of the exponential series (quotient test) $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n/n!$ implies that the terms tend to $0$.

Comment: A bigger point: prove that nowhere in your proof you are using the very fact you are trying to prove!

Comment: "Alternative proof" is not a useful title. It says nothing about the subject of the question.

Comment: Stinking Bishop, could you explain your comment?

Answer (score 1):

I can give a proof by using only the definition and an elementary result. The statement is equivalent to: $\lim\dfrac{a^{n}}{n!}=0$.

Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $N>a$. For $n>N$ we have

$\dfrac{a^{n}}{n!}=\dfrac{a}{1}\cdot \dfrac{a}{2}\cdot \ldots\cdot \dfrac{a}{N-1}\cdot \dfrac{a}{N}\cdot \ldots\cdot \dfrac{a}{n}$$\leq\,J\cdot \dfrac{a}{N}\cdot \dfrac{a}{N}\cdot \ldots\cdot \dfrac{a}{N}=J(\dfrac{a}{N})^{n-N+1}$

where $J=\dfrac{a^{N}}{(N-1)!}$ is a constant. (Because $a, N$ are constants.)

$\lim(\dfrac{a}{N})^{n-N+1}=(\dfrac{a}{N})^{-N+1}\lim(\dfrac{a}{N})^{n}$.

But by our choice of $N$ we have $\dfrac{a}{N}<1$ and hence $\lim(\dfrac{a}{N})^{n}=0$.

Thus $\lim\dfrac{a^{n}}{n!}=0$, and we are done!

Comment: This questions has the form of a common exercise, which implies that it has likely been asked an answered on this site in the past.  In such cases, please take some time to search for good duplicate targets.  This not only helps the asker (who is given a path to an answer), but it helps to maintain the overall quality of the database of questions and answers.

Comment: Also, please do not use the comments to beg for upvotes, or to complain about other people "copying" your answers.

Comment: Yes Mr.Henderson! Thank you for making me feel like a schoolboy in my sixties!!

Answer (score 0):

Let $$m<a<m+1, m<n.$$
Then $$\frac{a^n}{n!}=\frac{(a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot \ldots\cdot a)(a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot \ldots\cdot a)}{[(1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot\ldots \cdot m)(m+1)(m+2)(m+3)\ldots n]}=\frac{a^m}{m!}\frac{a}{m+1}\frac{a}{m+2}\frac{a}{m+3}\ldots\frac{a}{n}.$$
Next, $$\frac{a}{m+1}>\frac{a}{m+2}>\frac{a}{m+3}>\ldots>\frac{a}{n}.$$
Then we have $$0 <\frac{a^n}{n!}\le \frac{a^m}{m!}\left(\frac{a}{m+1}\right)^{n-m}.$$
Also, $$\frac{a}{m+1}<1\implies \lim_{n\to \infty}\left( \frac{a}{m+1}\right)^{n-m}\to 0.$$
Finally, by the sandwich theorem, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}\to 0,\quad a>0.$$

Comment: This questions has the form of a common exercise, which implies that it has likely been asked an answered on this site in the past.  In such cases, please take some time to search for good duplicate targets.  This not only helps the asker (who is given a path to an answer), but it helps to maintain the overall quality of the database of questions and answers.