# Show that $-x\ln\left(\frac{p}{x}\right)-(1-x)\ln\left(\frac{1-p}{1-x}\right)\geq \frac{(x-p)^2}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, upper-lower-bounds

> Let be $H:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ where $H(x):=-x\ln\left(\frac{p}{x}\right)-(1-x)\ln\left(\frac{1-p}{1-x}\right)$, where $0<p<1$.
> We know that  $H$ is infinitely many times continuously differentiable, and
> $$
> H'(x)=\ln\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1-p}\right)
> $$
> and for $k\geq 2$
> $$
> H^{(k)}(x)=\frac{(-1)^k(k-2)!}{x^{k-1}}+\frac{(k-2)!}{(1-x)^{k-1}}.
> $$
> Show that $H(x)\geq \frac{(x-p)^2}{2}$ for all $x\in (0,1)$. (The round parentheses mean that $0$ and $1$ are excluded.)

---

**My approach:**

I tried to show this statement by using the Taylor expansion and developed the Taylor series at $x=p$:

$\begin{align*}
&H(x\mid p)=\\
& H^{0}(p\mid p) (x-p)^0+H^{1}(p\mid p) (x-p)^1+H^{2}(p\mid p) \frac{(x-p)^2}{2!}+H^{3}(p\mid p) \frac{(x-p)^3}{3!}+H^{4}(p\mid p) \frac{(x-p)^4}{4!}+\dots\\
&=0+0+\left(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{1-p}\right)\frac{(x-p)^2}{2!}+H^{3}(p\mid p) \frac{(x-p)^3}{3!}+H^{4}(p\mid p) \frac{(x-p)^4}{4!}+\dots\\
\end{align*}$

As $\left(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{1-p}\right)>1$ it seems like that we only have to show that the remaining summands are $\geq 0$ if we add them up. But I failed to show this...

Any ideas? Or is this the wrong way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4070276/42969

Comment: Note that the sharper bound $2(x-p)^2$ holds, as demonstrated in the duplicate target.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139132/discussion-between-martin-r-and-george-tsoutsinos).

Comment: @MartinR, yes it does. I was only focussing on Talyor series and forgot about Taylors theorem :D ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for references. We bring everything on the l.h.s and we get

$f(x)=\dfrac{(x-p)^{2}}{2}+xln(p/x)+(1-x)ln\dfrac{1-p}{1-x}$.

Differentiating we get $f'(x)=x-p+ln\dfrac{p}{x}-ln\dfrac{1-p}{1-x}$ and we have:

$f'(p)=0$. We also have $f''(x)=\dfrac{x-x^{2}-1}{x(1-x)}<0$ which implies that the

function $f$ is concave and therefore local maximum is a global maximum!

$f''(p)=<0$ hence $p$ is a maximizer and $f(p)$ is the maximum.

But $f(p)=0$ therefore $f(x)\leq\,0$ which is what we had to prove!

Comment: If a question has been asked and answered before then it should be closed as a duplicate. If you have a new solution that has not been given before then you can add it to the duplicate target. The purpose of closing questions as a duplicate is to have all solutions at one place, compare https://math.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates.

Comment: OK, I missed it!

Comment: Dear Martin, I don't think that this story with duplicates makes a lot of sense! Almost everything can be found somewhere on the internet. I will give you an example that happened this afternoon. I posted an answer to a well known problem and after 15 minutes another guy posted the same proof! No one complained for duplicate! See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4529275/alternative-proof-about-divergence-of-of-n-an

Comment: If you have doubts that closing questions as a duplicate is good thing then you are welcome to discuss that at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com. Concerning your example: That question is already a duplicate.

Comment: The idea is to see a question and take pencil and paper to solve it. I know that many people instead of doing that start searching the internet for a solution. Let them fool themselves! But if someone searches thoroughly the internet then very few questions will remain which cannot be characterized as "duplicates"! We are not doing front line research here, we just solve problems to help people!

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos The goal of Math SE is to create a searchable repository of questions and answers.  Repeatedly duplicating posts does not further this goal.  Your attempt at whataboutism aside, it is far better to flag questions as duplicates.